# What is the sales tax for businesses in New York state?

Tags: united-states, new-york, sales-tax

I got a bill for an expensive item sold to me in upstate New York near Syracuse. The sales tax was 8.5%.

I read [a sales tax guide by New York City Department of Finance](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/finance/taxes/business-nys-sales-tax.page) that seems to say that the sales tax in New York state is 4% and the tax in New York City is an additional 4.5%. I interpret this as meaning that I should be paying the additional 4.5% only on items purchased in New York City. Did I interpret this wrong? Is the sales tax on general goods 8.5% no matter where they are purchased in New York?

Comment: Did you buy this in person in Syracuse? Did you have it shipped someplace?

Comment: Every county in NY has its own sales tax rate. Mine is 4%, for an 8% combined rate. Syracuse's is 8%, but it's possible you're buying in a different nearby county, or that there's a local municipality rate as well.

Answer (score 2):

While NY City does have a sales tax above the NY State base rate it isn't the only [jurisdiction with a higher rate.](https://www.tax.ny.gov/bus/st/rates.htm)

> **Sales tax rates**
>
> The combined sales and use tax rate equals the state rate (currently
>   4%) plus any local tax rate imposed by a city, county, or school
>   district. An additional sales tax rate of 0.375% applies to taxable
>   sales made within the Metropolitan Commuter Transportation District
>   (MCTD). The combined rates vary in each county and in cities that
>   impose sales tax.
>
> **Local taxing jurisdictions**
>
> New York's retail sales tax is a destination tax. The point of
>   delivery or the point at which possession is transferred by the seller
>   to the purchaser determines the rate of tax to be collected. Sales
>   delivered outside New York State are exempt from tax.

The state has a [tool to look up the tax by address](https://www8.tax.ny.gov/JRLA/jrlaStart) becasue it doesn't follow zip code boundaries. It also have a [PDF showing the various rates.](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/publications/sales/pub718.pdf)

Here are some example rates across the state:

> - Allegany 8½
> - Erie 8¾
> - Onondaga 8%
> - Ontario 7½
> - Orange 8⅛
> - Rockland 8⅜

Comment: I think the answer the OP is asking for is the second paragraph of the first quote. I think you should stress that front and center.